# Converting unicode to Chinese

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to get some Chinese text off a website online using python. When I get, it is surrounded by html tags and is like this:

> `我今天的<em class="hot">心情</em>不好。<br/>  I'm feeling blue today.`

(I had to put it as code to prevent the html tags from disappearing) However, once I use slicing to get rid of the html tags, I get:

> 我今天的心情ﾸﾍ好。

Why is this weird character appearing in the second to last spot? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, you can use [unicode category `\p{Han}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to filter Chinese characters:

```
>>> text = u'''我今天的<em class="hot">心情</em>不好。<br/> I'm feeling blue today.'''
>>> import regex
>>> print u''.join(regex.findall(r'\p{Han}+', text, flags=regex.UNICODE))
我今天的心情不好
```

Or, using [`unicodedata.name`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'a')
'LATIN SMALL LETTER A'
>>> unicodedata.name(u'我')
'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6211'
>>> unicodedata.name(u'今')
'CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4ECA'
```

---

```
>>> text = u'''我今天的<em class="hot">心情</em>不好。<br/> I'm feeling blue today.'''
>>> print u''.join(c for c in text if unicodedata.name(c).startswith('CJK'))
我今天的心情不好
```